# Переменная вместо имени переменной в $.post?

Tags: jquery

Как использовать переменную вместо имени переменной в $.post ?

```
$.post("index.php",{ this : val });
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что нужно. вместо `val` что-то подставить или вместо `this`, Может как-то более подробно опишите вопрос?

Comment: this заменить на  переменную this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оно?

```
var name   = 'test';
var params = {};

params[name] = 'val';

$.post("index.php", params);
```

Comment: Ура ! Заработало ! :) Спасибо.